# How ExecutorService works when submit a callable task with callback

Tags: java, multithreading, callback, executorservice

How to add custom check in executorService.submit() callback.
I want my thread not to do anything, whenever flag is true. If flag is false then it should work as usual.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.BasicThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
public class test{
    private static volatile boolean flag= false;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Callable<Boolean> callableTask = () -> {
            return isFlag();
        };
        Future a = submitAsync(callableTask);
        System.out.println("tartest"+a.get());
    }
    public static  Future submitAsync(Callable taskToRun) {
        ExecutorService e1 =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new BasicThreadFactory.Builder().namingPattern("").build());
        return e1.submit(() -> {
            try {
                if (flag) {
                    return;
                }
                taskToRun.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("garbage ---");
            }
        });
        // return e1.submit(taskToRun);
    }
    public static boolean isFlag() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here, a.get() is returning null. If I replace e1.submit(....) with e1.submit(taskToRun), which is commented in given code snippet then its working fine.  So why a.get() is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return e1.submit(() -> {
    try {
        if (flag) {
            return;
        }
        taskToRun.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("garbage ---");
    }
});
```

In this snippet, the lambda passed to `submit` method on `ExecutorService e1` is interpreted as a `Runnable` and that is why the return value is `null`. Check this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for more details. You need to pass the callable `taskToRun` itself to `e1.submit()` to be able to get the return value of the callable. Also, it would be cleaner to put the logic inside the `Callable` itself.


I have rewritten the sample code to achieve your requirement.

```
package stackoverflow.test;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.BasicThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class test{

  private static volatile boolean flag = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    Callable<Boolean> callableTask = () -> {
      if (flag) {
        System.out.println("Flag is true, returning without executing callable logic !");
        return false;
      }
      System.out.println("Flag is false, executing callable logic !");
      return isFlag();
    };

    Future a = submitAsync(callableTask);
    System.out.println("test " + a.get());
  }

  private static  Future<Boolean> submitAsync(Callable<Boolean> taskToRun) {
    ExecutorService e1 =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new BasicThreadFactory.Builder().namingPattern("").build());

    return e1.submit(taskToRun);
  }

  private static boolean isFlag() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `submitAsync` method returns a Future that is the result of calling ExecutorService.submit(Runnable).  From [the documentation of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

> Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future representing that task. The Future's get method will return null upon *successful* completion.

If you want to return a Future that yields a value, add return statements to your lambda, so it will be interpreted as a Callable instead of a Runnable:

```
    return taskToRun.call();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have a similar use case, trying to convert AsyncTasks to ExecutorService to return a List from a Room database. Another answer suggests using submit() on ExecutorService and get() on the Dao method (see stackoverflow.com/questions/52242933/room-database-query). Would appreciate your thoughts on that approach versus the approach of using a Callable and a Future.

Comment: @AJW I’m having trouble understanding what you are asking.  Consider creating a new question, that includes specific details, and includes enough code for readers to understand exactly what your problem is.